# iPhone SDK: UISearchBar: searchBarTextDidEndEditing not firing

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I'm implementing a search bar on my table, which should be pretty straight forward. I've got these:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar { 
 NSLog(@"searchBarTextDidBeginEditing");
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {    
    NSLog(@"The search text is: %@", searchText);
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    NSLog(@"searchBarTextDidEndEditing");
    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

And searchBarTextDidBeginEditing fires, and I get that message in my log, but when I tap outside the search bar, above the keyboard, I don't get the searchBarTextDidEndEditing event so I can't make the keyboard disappear – the message doesn't even appear in the log.

The textDidChange is working, so it's just searchBarTextDidBeginEditing that isn't.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Does the cursor disappear when you tap outside? You might have to unset first responder yourself.

Comment: It does not – keeps going. Is there another way to detect the tap outside the search bar, short of creating an invisible button or something?

Comment: You could try to do it in your view / view controller, or you could subclass UIApplication to catch the events.

Answer (score 9):

Even i faced the same problem.

Please find with the solution below

Implement Below methods

**1.searchBarTextDidEndEditing

2.searchBarSearchButtonClicked**

and make sure you `[UISearchchbar resignfirstresponder]`  in the second method mentioned above

Comment: This doesn't make much sense, there is no class/static method on UISearchBar with the name resignFirstResponder. I guess you mean to call that on the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Once I implemented **searchBarSearchButtonClicked** that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The method

> - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

is only called when `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` is called.

The best place to call `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` is in the method

> - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

In swift:

> - (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
> - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;

Comment: how does this translate in swift 4.2?